# kavod hatorah vs tznius/kol Isha

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, torah-service

if one is in a non orthodox synagogue and suddenly has thoughts of repentance as a woman is called up to the torah, what takes precedence? should he walk out because he feels this practice is incorrect or stay because there is a torah scroll on the bimah?

Comment: This question assumes that A) there is a prohibition to listen to a woman receiving an Aliyah, or else being present during said Aliyah, and B) there is a prohibition against leaving when there is a Torah being read. Can you please source these assumptions? That would greatly strengthen this question.

Comment: Would the question be any different had you simply written "someone is in a synagogue when a woman is called up"? What is the significance of the non-Orthodox  synagogue and the repentance?

Comment: In view of the previous comments, I agree that the Q needs editing and better focus. But, there is a rule mentioned in O.C. (have to locate it) that women do not receive aliyot because of *kavod hatzibbur*. Without delving into the extent of what that means, view the literal meaning of the phrase - "respect for the congregation." I.e., having a woman up there receiving an aliyah is disrespectful. If you're in the shul and a woman receives an aliyah, you wouldn't consider it personally disrespectful? This is not just an "Orthodox thing."

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760/759

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The whole existence of the unorthodox shul, where woman are called up to the Torah is in itself a Bizayon Hatorah (disgrace to the Torah) So leaving the temple, while this disgrace of the Torah is taking place, is an honor to the Torah rather than a bizayon. The original source of not calling women to the Torah was for Kavod Hatzibur, but once this is the proper way to do it, the existence of a synagogue (temple) which is based on disregard of Torah values is a disgrace to the Torah

Comment: Source? [15 char]

Comment: @DonielF source to WHAT?? To the fact that "the existence of a synagogue (temple) which is based on disregard of Torah values is a disgrace to the Torah"?? That is true by definition!

Comment: The questions was about a "non orthodox synagogue," not about "a synagogue which is based on disregard of Torah values." Whether or not you are correct, it is true "by definition" only because you equate the two, and so maybe you should support your answer better.

Comment: I meant source that it’s actually a disgrace that women are being called up. I can think of exactly one Gemara in Megillah that addresses women being called up to the Torah, and it’s only forbidden because of Kavod Tzibbur, not Kavod Torah. So can you please provide a source that what you’re saying is accurate?

Comment: @DonielF Reread what I wrote: The original source of not calling women to the Torah was for Kavod Hatzibur, but once this is the proper way to do it, the existence of a synagogue (temple) which is based on disregard of Torah values is a disgrace to the Torah.

Comment: @please define "unorthodox" - Do you mean reform? conservative? progressive? 7th day Adventist? JforJ?? which of these do YOU think are NOT a disgrace to Torah?

Comment: First of all, your answer would be greatly improved by citing that Gemara in it. Second, couldn’t you argue that if it’s just Kavod Tzibbur that the Tzibbur can decide whether it wants to uphold that or not? Why is that considered a breach in Torah values?

Comment: @DonielF Halacha tells us what is Kavod hatzibur not "unorthodox synagogue" members.

Comment: Can’t the Tzibbur be mochel on their kavod?

Comment: @DonielF The fact that they forbade women to get aliyos because of kavod hatzibur shows that they didnt leave it up to every congregation's fancy, but they said this is a kavod which is mandatory.

Comment: I’m not sure how accurate that is. I’m going to ask for a source again - I’m just not sure I agree with that logic.

Comment: @DonielF I think that should be edited to read "I'm not sure whether I want to agree.." .

Comment: I’m not attacking anyone here (or at least not intending to). I’ve said my piece, you’ve said your piece, we don’t agree with each other. All I’ve asked is that you bring a source that what you’re saying is correct, and I infer from your answer that you don’t have one to provide.